# Pointer to base class in derived class as a member variable

Tags: c++, inheritance

I saw from a code that a derived class has a member variable that is a pointer to its base class, like this

```
class Base {
private: 
    int a;
    int b;
    int d;
    void init(){// ... }
public:
    Base(int a_ , int b_) :  a(a_), b(b_){
     init();
    }
    Base() = default; 
    int getA(){return a;}

}


class Derived : public Base {
    private: 
       Base* base;
       int c; 
    public: 
       Derived(int a_, int b_, int c_): base(new(Base(a_, b_)), c(c_){base->getA() // for initialization of another function};
    }

int main(){

Derived derived(0,0,0); 
}
```

Is this something smart? Why or how this could be useful to have a Base member inside the Derived Class, if we could just call public or protected methods of Base from Derived?

Another question is: I get two times Base constructed, right? one for the derived object that call the default constructor, and the other one from the initialisation list that call the non-default constructor.

Edit: 
The code I present is a VERY short version of what I stepped into. They use the base member in derived to do a lot of stuff, i.e. calling members of Base as parameters to other functions or initialising members of Derived. My thoughts is that it might be just for encapsulation. But it is certainly weird.

Hope my question is not too confusing! I just dont understand what could the main use of something like this!

Comment: No, absolutely not smart. Maybe there’s context which makes this meaningful but your specific example is 100% meaningless, and has at least three additional problems: (1) it violates the rule of three, (2) relatedly, it uses unnecessary manual memory management, (3) the base class `init` function is an anti-pattern that should be replaced by just using a constructor.

Answer (score 3):

The usefulness (or smartness) cannot be established by seeing this code (unless this is the final version of those classes in which case it seems useless to instantiate a base class inside the derived class because it is not used),it depends on how you are going to use the base object inside the class Derived.

Notice that the base variable inside Derived class as nothing to do with the Base class that the Derived class inherit from.

The code instantiate 2 object one is the one named derived that is of class Derived, the other one is the one named base inside the derived class (instantiated with the new inside the derived constructor).

Warning: the code above, without the definition of a destructor for Derived class cause a missing delete of a Base class object when a Derived class object is destructed.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you have it constructed 2 times and even more: you never destroy this second dynamically allocated class.
This looks strange